# Breeze Project - Null Fields Removed

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

If I run a breeze projection query:

```
var item;
breeze.EntityQuery
.from("SomeTable")
.where("Id", "==", id)
.select("A, B, C, D")
.using(myEntityManager).execute()
.then(function(data) { item = ko.observable(data.results[0]); });
```

And say the row in the table, B and C are NULL, I'll get back an object without B and C.

```
{
A: "somevalue",
B: "someothervalue"
}
```

In the UI I have:

```
<div data-bind="with: item">
<span data-bind="text: A" />
<span data-bind="text: B" />
<span data-bind="text: C" />
<span data-bind="text: D" />
</div>
```

I then get the error -

> ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "with: function(){return
>   item}" Message: Unable to process binding "text:
>   function(){return B}" 
>   Message: 'B' is undefined

Am I missing something? How can I get B and C in the results, with a value of null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your situation, modeled after the [Northwind sample database](https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/) that is available for interactive testing at http://learn.breezejs.com/

```
var myEntityManager = new breeze.EntityManager('api/northwind');

function Employee() {
    this.FirstName = ko.observable(null);
    this.LastName = ko.observable(null);
}
Employee.prototype.init = function (data) {
    if (data) {
        this.FirstName(data.FirstName);
        this.LastName(data.LastName);
    } else {
        this.FirstName(null);
        this.LastName(null);
    }
};
Employee.prototype.loadFromId = function (id) {
    var self = this;
    breeze.EntityQuery.from("Employees")
    .where("EmployeeId", "==", id)
    .select("FirstName, LastName")
    .using(myEntityManager).execute()
    .then(function (data) {
        self.init(data.results[0]);
    })
    .fail(function () {
        self.init(null);
        // also show or log error message
    });
};
```

usage:

```
var viewModel = new Employee();
viewModel.loadFromId(1);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The key point is that you need an actual view model *first*. You are not writing breeze code, you are writing Knockout code, with Breeze being only a means of filling your viewmodels with data.

So if your view requires properties `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`, you need to create a viewmodel first that provides them. Make sure your views work with empty view models. Only after that you can turn to the task of filling them with data.

Comment: Ok, but I would have expected breeze to have returned the fields, with a value of null. What if knowing the value = null is important? Does it do the same for a bit of 0 or a string of empty?

Comment: And, querying an entity does not work this way. If you query an entity, no projection, no client side model class, you're still getting a breeze.entity with null fields present.

Comment: I can only say that this code works as it is on the http://learn.breezejs.com/ site.

Comment: @user Point being, I have only cursory experience with Breeze, but I know my way around Knockout reasonably well. That's the point of view expressed in the last paragraph of my answer. Whatever method of loading data into your viewmodels you end up with – be it Breeze or plain JSON or a REST webservice or anything – you need a solid viewmodel *first*. How exactly Breeze returns entities is superficial in nature. You can always adapt incoming data to your viewmodel, so long as that viewmodel itself works.